# Round each instance in Sumproduct before sum

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying SUMPRODUCT Formula on lets say Column A and Column B. Column A has Patient referrals and Column B has percentage referred for each hospital. I am using this syntax:
ROUND(SUMPRODUCT(A1:A10,B1:B10),0). However, the formula rounds the total result instead of Rounding at every instance. For example this is what I want to achieve through a formula:

(ROUND(10*20%),0)+ (ROUND(15*30%),0)+(ROUND(125*50%),0)

Instead the formula works this way:

ROUND((10*20%)+(15*30%)+(125*50%),0)

This doesnot give the same result. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

```
=sumproduct(round(A1:A3,0),round(B1:B3,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this with SUMPRODUCT. Formally you can use this function, however it will be equivalent to using SUM. It is not the same if you round each factor separately or you round products. See the screenshot.
[image: Round with Sumproduct]